# OpenGL: ERROR: Compiled vertex shader was corrupt

Tags: c++, opengl

This was my vertex shader before it was corrupt:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 m;
uniform mat4 v;
uniform mat4 p;

out vec2 texPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = p * v * m * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    texPos = vec2(0, 0);
}
```

And this is my vertex shader after it was corrupt:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexPos;

uniform mat4 m;
uniform mat4 v;
uniform mat4 p;

out vec2 texPos;

void main() {
    gl_Position = p * v * m * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    texPos = vec2(0, 0);
}
```

The difference between them is just a `layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexPos`. How and why did this 'corruption' happen?

EDIT: here's the loadProgram function that is used to load the shaders:

```
GLuint Framework::loadProgram(string vpath, string fpath) {
    GLuint v, f;
    stringstream ss;
    char log[512];

    v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fstream vf(vpath);
    if (vf.good()) {
        ss << vf.rdbuf();
        const GLchar* g = ss.str().c_str();
        glShaderSource(v, 1, &g, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(v);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(v, 512, nullptr, log);
        cout << "Vertex Shader: " << log << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Bad path " << vpath.c_str() << endl;
        return static_cast<GLuint>(-1);
    }

    ss.str("");
    f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    fstream ff(fpath);
    if (ff.good()) {
        ss << ff.rdbuf();
        const GLchar* g = ss.str().c_str();
        glShaderSource(f, 1, &g, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(f);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(f, 512, nullptr, log);
        cout << "Fragment Shader: " << log << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Bad path " << fpath.c_str() << endl;
        return static_cast<GLuint>(-1);
    }

    GLuint prog;
    prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, v);
    glAttachShader(prog, f);
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, 512, nullptr, log);
    cout << "Program: " << log;
    glDeleteShader(v);
    glDeleteShader(f);
    return prog;
}
```

It just says it's corrupted... And I have no idea where it had gone wrong. 
Here's what I got when I run the program:

> Vertex Shader:
>   Fragment Shader:
>   Program: ERROR: Compiled vertexshader was corrupt.

Comment: Please show the code where you load/compile the shader and the complete error message.

Comment: @BDL I've posted everything I could post so far. Additional information can be given if you want - I am just trying to write a lite framework. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @genpfault I am quite new to StackOverflow... I hope the edit I've done just now helps! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It's the problem of the loadProgram function, that vertex shader's `ss.str().c_str()` return a single '\0' character. I have no idea why fragment shader's string stream works well, though.

So here's the code now:

```
GLuint Framework::loadProgram(string vpath, string fpath) {
    GLuint v, f;
    stringstream ss;
    char log[512];

    v = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fstream vf(vpath);
    if (vf.good()) {
        ss << vf.rdbuf();
        string str = ss.str();
        const GLchar* g = str.c_str();
        glShaderSource(v, 1, &g, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(v);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(v, 512, nullptr, log);
        cout << "Vertex Shader: " << log << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Bad path " << vpath.c_str() << endl;
        return static_cast<GLuint>(-1);
    }

    ss.str("");
    f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    fstream ff(fpath);
    if (ff.good()) {
        ss << ff.rdbuf();
        string str = ss.str();
        const GLchar* g = str.c_str();
        glShaderSource(f, 1, &g, nullptr);
        glCompileShader(f);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(f, 512, nullptr, log);
        cout << "Fragment Shader: " << log << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Bad path " << fpath.c_str() << endl;
        return static_cast<GLuint>(-1);
    }

    GLuint prog;
    prog = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(prog, v);
    glAttachShader(prog, f);
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, 512, nullptr, log);
    cout << "Program: " << log;
    glDeleteShader(v);
    glDeleteShader(f);
    return prog;
}
```